# How to read text and images from this URL?

Tags: android

How could i read the text from this url for each row and the images.

And the populate a row for each item. Populating the images in a imageview and the text in a text view?

http://www.movieweb.com/movies/2011/week

Comment: The easiest way is to use Cinemadroid :P

Comment: Put some instructions to the URL and some info about it so I can give you the correct answer.

Comment: Btw way I'm not actually trying to use that URL. I just wanted a example

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you wanted to do something like this you would have to know how to parse the data coming in from the URL. For instance you would open up an http connection to the website and then download that page and its data and then once you have it it you would parse it for information you want. In particular, its a little difficult because it doesn't have a provider service to give you that data in a clean form like XML/JSON etc. Give it a try, first start off by looking through the page's source code on a browser and see if there is some kind of pattern you notice.

It's all fair game!

Answer (score 1):

You apparently need an HTML parser. I greatly recommend you to give a try at [Apache Jericho](http://jericho.htmlparser.net/docs/index.html). Also note that tagsoup is built-in android, but Jericho is just a perfect match, and quite fast, for not-very-well structured html, I mean real world html.

But the problem can come from get jericho work on android. You could consider building your own web service that would parse html from your source and format it in something like JSON/XML as @JoxTraex suggested.

Regards,
 Stéphane

Comment: Any examples of this in android??

Comment: There is no difference with apache Jericho for java sdk. Just try to compile it. I think it works, I remember having talked with the author of CineShowTimes, the dev team uses this parser I think. The code is on google code.

Comment: Do you have gtalk or anything?

Comment: I just downloaded your application! About to use it and give it a rating! =)